# In Python, what is the difference between ".append()" and "+= []"? 

Tags: python, list, concatenation

What is the difference between:

```
some_list1 = []
some_list1.append("something")
```

and

```
some_list2 = []
some_list2 += ["something"]
```

Comment: append if for a single item. maybe you mean `extend`.

Comment: For the more interesting case of `+=` vs `extend`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653298/concatenating-two-lists-difference-between-and-extend

Comment: `+=` vs `append` https://stackoverflow.com/q/252703/6674599

Answer (score 181, accepted):

For your case the only difference is performance: append is twice as fast.

```
Python 3.0 (r30:67507, Dec  3 2008, 20:14:27) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.Timer('s.append("something")', 's = []').timeit()
0.20177424499999999
>>> timeit.Timer('s += ["something"]', 's = []').timeit()
0.41192320500000079

Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Apr 18 2007, 08:51:08) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.Timer('s.append("something")', 's = []').timeit()
0.23079359499999999
>>> timeit.Timer('s += ["something"]', 's = []').timeit()
0.44208112500000141
```

In general case `append` will add one item to the list, while `+=` will copy *all* elements of right-hand-side list into the left-hand-side list.

**Update: perf analysis**

Comparing bytecodes we can assume that `append` version wastes cycles in `LOAD_ATTR` + `CALL_FUNCTION`, and += version -- in `BUILD_LIST`. Apparently `BUILD_LIST` outweighs `LOAD_ATTR` + `CALL_FUNCTION`.

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile("s = []; s.append('spam')", '', 'exec'))
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (s)
              6 LOAD_NAME                0 (s)
              9 LOAD_ATTR                1 (append)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 ('spam')
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 POP_TOP
             19 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(compile("s = []; s += ['spam']", '', 'exec'))
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (s)
              6 LOAD_NAME                0 (s)
              9 LOAD_CONST               0 ('spam')
             12 BUILD_LIST               1
             15 INPLACE_ADD
             16 STORE_NAME               0 (s)
             19 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

We can improve performance even more by removing `LOAD_ATTR` overhead:

```
>>> timeit.Timer('a("something")', 's = []; a = s.append').timeit()
0.15924410999923566
```

Comment: +1: This is very interesting.  I use append anyway, because it results in clearer code.  But I didn't realize there was a performance difference.  If anything, I would have expected append to be slower, since it's a guaranteed function call, while I presumed += would be optimized further.

Comment: Isn't there also a functional difference? For instance let **a = []**, **b = [4,5,6]**, here if you do **c = a.append(b)** then c would be a list of list **[[4,5,6]]** while **c += b**; would lead to a simple list **c = [4,5,6]**.

Comment: just to set things straight: += gives a better performance than extend or append as long as your input is in the right format. What takes time in the current example is the creation of the ['something'] list. += is about 15% faster

Comment: @Joe If you're comparing `append` vs `+=`, then you *must* include creation of the list as part of the measurement.  Otherwise it'd be a different question (`extend` vs `+=`).

Comment: @jamesdlin yup! But it's easy to be mistaken unless you already know this. A little additional precision has never hurt anyone, right?

Comment: @rph No, there is no functional difference. To comply with the question, your example should be `c += [b]` instead of `c += b`, so you missed the brackets.

Answer (score 58):

```
>>> a=[]
>>> a.append([1,2])
>>> a
[[1, 2]]
>>> a=[]
>>> a+=[1,2]
>>> a
[1, 2]
```

See that append adds a single element to the list, which may be anything. `+=[]` joins the lists.

Comment: Voting this up because this is an important distinction between the two. Good work.

Answer (score 53):

In the example you gave, there is no difference, in terms of output, between `append` and `+=`.  But there is a difference between `append` and `+` (which the question originally asked about).

```
>>> a = []
>>> id(a)
11814312
>>> a.append("hello")
>>> id(a)
11814312

>>> b = []
>>> id(b)
11828720
>>> c = b + ["hello"]
>>> id(c)
11833752
>>> b += ["hello"]
>>> id(b)
11828720
```

As you can see, `append` and `+=` have the same result; they add the item to the list, without producing a new list.  Using `+` adds the two lists and produces a new list.

Comment: There *is* difference between append and +=.

Comment: There's the fact that `append` adds one entry to the list, while += adds as many as there are in the other list (i.e. aliases to `extend`).  But he/she knows that already, judging by the way the question was written.  Is there some other difference I'm missing?

Comment: There's a difference because an augmented assignment introduces rebinding (explanation in my answer).

Answer (score 32):

+= is an assignment. When you use it you're really saying ‘some_list2= some_list2+['something']’. Assignments involve rebinding, so:

```
l= []

def a1(x):
    l.append(x) # works

def a2(x):
    l= l+[x] # assign to l, makes l local
             # so attempt to read l for addition gives UnboundLocalError

def a3(x):
    l+= [x]  # fails for the same reason
```

The += operator should also normally create a new list object like list+list normally does:

```
>>> l1= []
>>> l2= l1

>>> l1.append('x')
>>> l1 is l2
True

>>> l1= l1+['x']
>>> l1 is l2
False
```

However in reality:

```
>>> l2= l1
>>> l1+= ['x']
>>> l1 is l2
True
```

This is because Python lists implement [__iadd__()](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) to make a += augmented assignment short-circuit and call list.extend() instead. (It's a bit of a strange wart this: it usually does what you meant, but for confusing reasons.)

In general, if you're appending/extended an existing list, and you want to keep the reference to the same list (instead of making a new one), it's best to be explicit and stick with the append()/extend() methods.

Answer (score 22):

```
 some_list2 += ["something"]
```

is actually

```
 some_list2.extend(["something"])
```

for one value, there is no difference.
Documentation states, that:

> `s.append(x)`     same as `s[len(s):len(s)] = [x]` 
>   `s.extend(x)`     same as `s[len(s):len(s)] = x`

Thus obviously `s.append(x)` is same as `s.extend([x])`

Comment: s.append takes an arbitrary type and adds it to the list; It's a true append. s.extend takes an iterable (usually a list), and merges the iterable into s, modfiying the memory addresses of s. These are *not* the same.

Answer (score 10):

The difference is that ***concatenate*** will flatten the resulting list, whereas ***append*** will keep the levels intact:

So for example with:

```
myList = [ ]
listA = [1,2,3]
listB = ["a","b","c"]
```

Using append, you end up with a list of lists:

```
>> myList.append(listA)
>> myList.append(listB)
>> myList
[[1,2,3],['a','b','c']]
```

Using concatenate instead, you end up with a flat list:

```
>> myList += listA + listB
>> myList
[1,2,3,"a","b","c"]
```

Answer (score 6):

The performance tests here are not correct:

1. You shouldn't run the profile only once.
2. If comparing `append` vs. `+=[]` a number of times, you should declare `append` as a local function.
3. Time results are different on different python versions: 64- and 32-bit.

e.g.

```py
timeit.Timer('for i in xrange(100): app(i)', 's = [] ; app = s.append').timeit()
```

Good tests can be found here: [Python list append vs. +=[]](https://web.archive.org/web/20171201054245/http://www.markandclick.com:80/1/post/2012/01/python-list-append-vs.html)

Comment: still, the += tests in that page uses `+= [one_var]`. If we omit creating lists, += becomes the fastest option.

Answer (score 4):

The rebinding behaviour mentioned in other answers does matter in certain circumstances:

```
>>> a = ([],[])
>>> a[0].append(1)
>>> a
([1], [])
>>> a[1] += [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

That's because augmented assignment always rebinds, even if the object was mutated in-place. The rebinding here happens to be `a[1] = *mutated list*`, which doesn't work for tuples.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the aspects described in the other answers, append and +[] have very different behaviors when you're trying to build a list of lists.

```
>>> list1=[[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> list2=[5,6]
>>> list3=list1+list2
>>> list3
[[1, 2], [3, 4], 5, 6]
>>> list1.append(list2)
>>> list1
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

list1+['5','6'] adds '5' and '6' to the list1 as individual elements.  list1.append(['5','6']) adds the list ['5','6'] to the list1 as a single element.

Answer (score 3):

"+" **does not** mutate the list

.append() **mutates** the old list

Answer (score 1):

As of today and Python 3.6, the results provided by @Constantine are no longer the same.

```
Python 3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  8 2020, 02:54:21) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.Timer('s.append("something")', 's = []').timeit()
0.0447923709944007
>>> timeit.Timer('s += ["something"]', 's = []').timeit()
0.04335783299757168
```

It seems that `append` and `+=` now have an equal performance, whereas the compilation differences haven't changed at all:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile("s = []; s.append('spam')", '', 'exec'))
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (s)
              4 LOAD_NAME                0 (s)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                1 (append)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 ('spam')
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 POP_TOP
             14 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(compile("s = []; s += ['spam']", '', 'exec'))
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (s)
              4 LOAD_NAME                0 (s)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 ('spam')
              8 BUILD_LIST               1
             10 INPLACE_ADD
             12 STORE_NAME               0 (s)
             14 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

let's take an example first

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=list1     (that means they points to same object)

if we do 
list1=list1+[5]    it will create a new object of list
print(list1)       output [1,2,3,4,5] 
print(list2)       output [1,2,3,4]

but if we append  then 
list1.append(5)     no new object of list created
print(list1)       output [1,2,3,4,5] 
print(list2)       output [1,2,3,4,5]

extend(list) also do the same work as append it just append a list instead of a 
single variable
```

Answer (score 0):

The append() method adds a single item to the existing list

```
some_list1 = []
some_list1.append("something")
```

So here the some_list1 will get modified.

Updated:

Whereas using + to combine the elements of lists (more than one element) in the existing list similar to the extend (as corrected by [Flux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5916915/flux)).

```
some_list2 = []
some_list2 += ["something"]
```

So here the some_list2 and ["something"] are the two lists that are combined.

Comment: This is wrong. `+=` does not return a new list. The [Programming FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-does-a-tuple-i-item-raise-an-exception-when-the-addition-works) says: "... for lists, `__iadd__` is equivalent to calling `extend` on the list and returning the list. That's why we say that for lists, `+=` is a "shorthand" for `list.extend`". You can also see this for yourself in the CPython source code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.2/Objects/listobject.c#L1000-L1011