# Python append() vs. + operator on lists, why do these give different results?

Tags: python, list, append, nested-lists

Why do these two operations (`append()` resp. `+`) give different results?

```
>>> c = [1, 2, 3]
>>> c
[1, 2, 3]
>>> c += c
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
>>> c = [1, 2, 3]
>>> c.append(c)
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, [...]]
>>>
```

In the last case there's actually an infinite recursion. `c[-1]` and `c` are the same. Why is it different with the `+` operation?

Comment: with all due respect to a viable new question: I rolled back to the original question to keep it clean (1 question per thread, see SO FAQ). Please ask a new one or ask follow-up questions inside the comment-threads below each answer. *Note: your edits are not lost, click the history and you can copy/paste it into a new question.*

Comment: Similar for `+=`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725782/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-append-and

Comment: it seems that it gives different ans, but not like that. If you want to add a value using + operator you have o use [] sign. 
c += [c] will give you same result as append.

Comment: @SharifChowdhury I believe you will get the same result

Answer (score 181, accepted):

#### To explain "why":

The [`+` operation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) adds the [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) elements to the original array. The [`array.append`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html?highlight=append#array.array.append) operation inserts the array (or any object) into the end of the original array, which results in a *reference to self* in that spot (hence the infinite recursion in your case with lists, though with arrays, you'd receive a type error).

The difference here is that the `+` operation acts specific when you add an array (it's overloaded like others, see [this chapter](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) on sequences) by concatenating the element. The `append`-method however does literally what you ask: append the object on the right-hand side that you give it (the array or any other object), instead of taking its elements.

#### An alternative

Use [`extend()`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html?highlight=append#array.array.extend) if you want to use a function that acts similar to the `+` operator (as others have shown here as well). It's not wise to do the opposite: to try to mimic `append` with the `+` operator for lists (see my [earlier link](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) on why). More on lists below:

#### Lists

[edit] Several commenters have suggested that the question is about lists and not about arrays. The question has changed, though I should've included this earlier.

Most of the above about `array`s also applies to lists:

- The `+` operator concatenates two lists together. The operator will return a new list object.
- `List.append` does not *append* one list with another, but *appends a single object* (which here is a `list`) at the end of your current list. Adding `c` to itself, therefore, leads to infinite recursion.
- As with arrays, you can use [`List.extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to add extend a list with another list (or `iterable`). This will change your current list *in situ*, as opposed to `+`, which returns a new list.

#### Little history

For fun, a little history: the [birth of the array module in Python](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/python/search/hypermail/python-1993/0018.html) in February 1993. it might surprise you, but arrays were added way after sequences and lists came into existence.

Comment: +1 because I always upvote accurate information.  Links to official docs are always a plus!

Comment: Another part of "why": sane people expect `+` to be symmetric: concatenate list with list.

Comment: +1, Good point Beni (while I could consider it just as "sane" to say "the object on the rh side is appended to the array on lh side", but personally find the current behavior more sensible).

Comment: if an element is single string, e.g. s = 'word', l = ['this', 'is']. Then l.append(s) and l+s should be the same. Am I correct?

Comment: It is not same, to get same answer, you should use l+[s], otherwise it will throw 'TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list'.

Comment: Why are you linking to the `array.array` docs??

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, the links go to the `array.html` pages of the reference docs. The `#array.array...` you see in the links are the id of the item in that page. The topic is on arrays, so yeah, that's really all there is to it: convenience links to the docs (of 12yr ago).

Comment: @Abel although the `array.array` and `list` types work identically in this particular regard, the question was about `list` objects, not `array.array` objects, unless something was changed in an edit? Note, you cannot actually get the equivalent of `[1, 2, 3, [...]]` with `array.array` objects, it would throw a type error if you did `my_array.append(my_array)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Ah wait, lists vs arrays. I’ll check tomorrow to update my answer a little, I see now, tx!

Comment: @Abel yeah, unfortunately, the modern docs kind merged the "mutable sequence" operations into one [table summarizing their operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types). But you can also link to the [tutorial which documents some of these operations for list objects specifically](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: Python does not have arrays and it's not a minor issue to conflate them with lists.

Comment: @RickO'Shea the original question and title had no reference to lists (though it could be inferred from the text). Note that Python supports arrays, or at least, it calls them "arrays". I used links to original documentation of Python. But you're right, it may be time to update my answer a little.

Answer (score 33):

The concatenation operator [`+`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) is a binary infix operator which, when applied to lists, returns a new list containing all the elements of each of its two operands. The [`list.append()`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method is a `mutator` on [`list`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) which appends its single `object` argument (in your specific example the list `c`) to the subject [`list`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). In your example this results in `c` appending a reference to itself (hence the infinite recursion).

#### An alternative to '+' concatenation

The [`list.extend()`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method is also a mutator method which concatenates its `sequence` argument with the subject [`list`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). Specifically, it appends each of the elements of `sequence` in iteration order.

#### An aside

Being an operator, [`+`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) returns the result of the expression as a new value. Being a non-chaining `mutator` method, [`list.extend()`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) modifies the subject list in-place and returns nothing.

#### Arrays

*I've added this due to the potential confusion which the Abel's answer above may cause by mixing the discussion of lists, sequences and arrays.*
[`Arrays`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) were added to Python after sequences and lists, as a more efficient way of storing arrays of integral data types. Do not confuse `arrays` with `lists`. They are not the same.

*From the [array docs](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html):*

Arrays are sequence types and behave very much like lists, except that the type of objects stored in them is constrained. The type is specified at object creation time by using a type code, which is a single character.

Answer (score 22):

`append` is appending an element to a list. if you want to extend the list with the new list you need to use `extend`.

```
>>> c = [1, 2, 3]
>>> c.extend(c)
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I thought it's quite clear *why* the results are different, because operations are not the same! if it would appear that `+` and `extend` produce different results that we'd have something to think about.

Comment: +1: Why I dislike "why" questions: `append` and `+` are different.  That's why.  I like this answer because offers what do do that makes more sense.

Comment: Isn't this site about answering the questions asked? People ask why PHP is called PHP and why `__lt__` could not be overloaded in Python (nowadays it can). Why-questions are the most essential ones but often the trickiest to answer: they ask for the essence, not for a pointer to the manual. And of course: if you dislike a question (I dislike most), then don't answer ;-)

Comment: For further demonstration, maybe show `c += [c]` and `c.append(c[:])` too.

Comment: @Abel: Why is `a+b != a*b`?  They're different operations.  That's the answer.  "Why" isn't as helpful as other questions, like "How can I append properly?"  Or "What's wrong with this append that leads to infinite recursion?"  Questions of the form "What do I do to X" or "What went wrong when I did X"?  Or "What should I do instead of X" will also help someone learn, but will provide focused, usable, actionable answers.

Comment: Interesting side discussion, not sure if we should... but...: If you ask "how can I do X", you answer `obj.X` or `obj+X`. The more elaborate answerer will also explain *why* you should choose either, to teach the asker how to think about it. Yes, I agree, *what*, *how* etc can give very simple, very clear answers, most of the time. *why* is often called the only question with infinite answers.But it teaches us to think. *How do we live is boring* (imo), *why do we live* is much more intriguing. Python started out with the question "why do we need a new language". The answer was the language.

Answer (score 9):

Python lists are heterogeneous that is the elements in the same list can be any type of object. The expression: `c.append(c)` appends the object `c` what ever it may be to the list. In the case it makes the list itself a member of the list.

The expression `c += c` adds two lists together and assigns the result to the variable `c`. The overloaded `+` operator is defined on lists to create a new list whose contents are the elements in the first list and the elements in the second list.

So these are really just different expressions used to do different things by design.

Answer (score 7):

The method you're looking for is `extend()`. From the Python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
list.append(x)
    Add an item to the end of the list; equivalent to a[len(a):] = [x].

list.extend(L)
    Extend the list by appending all the items in the given list; equivalent to a[len(a):] = L.

list.insert(i, x)
    Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so a.insert(0, x) inserts at the front of the list, and a.insert(len(a), x) is equivalent to a.append(x).
```

Answer (score 3):

you should use extend()

```
>>> c=[1,2,3]
>>> c.extend(c)
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

other info: [append vs. extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend)

Answer (score 2):

See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> list.append(x)
>
> - Add an item to the end of the list; equivalent to a[len(a):] = [x].
>
> list.extend(L)
>    - Extend the list by appending all the items in the given list;
>   equivalent to a[len(a):] = L.

`c.append(c)` "appends" c to itself *as an element*. Since a list is a reference type, this creates a recursive data structure.

`c += c` is equivalent to `extend(c)`, which appends *the elements of c* to c.