# + and += operators are different?

Tags: python, list, operators

```
>>> c = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(c, id(c))
[1, 2, 3] 43955984
>>> c += c
>>> print(c, id(c))
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] 43955984
>>> del c
>>> c = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(c, id(c))
[1, 2, 3] 44023976
>>> c = c + c
>>> print(c, id(c))
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] 26564048
```

What's the difference? are += and + not supposed to be merely syntactic sugar?

Comment: Your example clear demonstrates that they are not. += is clearly add to this object and x = a + b (even if a = b = x) would clearly create a new result and assign it to the LHS. I think it would be counter productive to check every addition to see if it were a simple addition (as above) and optimise that to +=.

Comment: this question has some nice additional information on list concatenation operations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022031/python-append-vs-operator-on-lists-why-do-these-give-different-results

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[docs explain it very well](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__), I think:

> `__iadd__()`, etc.
>   These methods are called to implement the augmented arithmetic assignments (`+=, -=, *=, /=, //=, %=, **=, <<=, >>=, &=, ^=, |=`). **These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying `self`) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, `self`).** If a specific method is not defined, the augmented assignment falls back to the normal methods. For instance, to execute the statement `x += y`, where `x` is an instance of a class that has an `__iadd__()`  method, `x.__iadd__(y)` is called.

`+=` are designed to implement in-place modification. in case of simple addition, new object created and it's labelled using already-used name (`c`).

Also, you'd notice that such behaviour of `+=` operator only possible because of mutable nature of lists. Integers - an immutable type - won't produce the same result:

```
>>> c = 3
>>> print(c, id(c))
3 505389080
>>> c += c
>>> print(c, id(c))
6 505389128
```

Comment: Another point is the order of evaluation / precedence. in `c= c + c` the `c + c` is evaluated before assignment `c=`, where as in `c+=c` there are no two different operations per se.

Answer (score 3):

They are not same

c += c append a copy of content of c to c itself

c = c + c create new object with c + c

Answer (score 2):

For

```
foo = []
```

`foo+=foo` is syntactic sugar for `foo.extend(foo)` (and not `foo = foo + foo`)

In the first case, you're just appending members of a list into another (and not creating a new one).

The `id` changes in the second case because a new list is created by adding two lists. It's incidental that both are the same and the result is being bound to the same identifier than once pointed to them.

If you rephrase this question with different lists (and not c itself), it will probably become clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The += operator appends the second list to the first, but the modification is in-place, so the ID remains the same.

When you use + , a new list is created, and the final "c" is a new list, so it has a different ID.

The end result is the same for both operations though.