# How are Python in-place operator functions different than the standard operator functions?

Tags: python, function, operator-keyword

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html):

> Many operations have an “in-place”
> version. The following functions
> provide a more primitive access to
> in-place operators than the usual
> syntax does; for example, the
> statement x += y is equivalent to x =
> operator.iadd(x, y). Another way to
> put it is to say that z =
> operator.iadd(x, y) is equivalent to
> the compound statement z = x; z += y.

Questions:

- Why isn't `operator.iadd(x, y)` equivalent to `z = x; z += y`?
- How does `operator.iadd(x, y)` differ from `operator.add(x, y)`?

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027284/and-operators-are-different), but I'm not interested in Python class methods; just regular operators on built-in Python types.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, you need to understand the difference between `__add__` and `__iadd__`.

An object's `__add__` method is regular addition: it takes two parameters, returns their sum, and doesn't modify either parameter.

An object's `__iadd__` method also takes two parameters, but makes the change in-place, modifying the contents of the first parameter. Because this requires object mutation, immutable types (like the standard number types) shouldn't have an `__iadd__` method.

`a + b` uses `__add__`.  `a += b` uses `__iadd__` if it exists; if it doesn't, it emulates it via `__add__`, as in `tmp = a + b; a = tmp`.  `operator.add` and `operator.iadd` differ in the same way.

To the other question: `operator.iadd(x, y)` isn't equivalent to `z = x; z += y`, because if no `__iadd__` exists `__add__` will be used instead.  You need to assign the value to ensure that the result is stored in both cases: `x = operator.iadd(x, y)`.

You can see this yourself easily enough:

```
import operator
a = 1
operator.iadd(a, 2)
# a is still 1, because ints don't have __iadd__; iadd returned 3

b = ['a']
operator.iadd(b, ['b'])
# lists do have __iadd__, so b is now ['a', 'b']
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__

Notice that augmented assignments could but does not have to modify object in-place

Comment: Why is python designed with augmented assignments operating in-place? It's kinda feels counter-intuitive because when we learn the language we usually learn augmented assignments with immutable values first. So it's a bit unexpected that with mutable values augmented assignment behaves differently. Feels rather implicit and bug-prone.

Comment: @max that sounds like the fault of whoever designed the learning materials. The purpose of augmented assignment is quite clear: [PEP 203](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because some Python objects are immutable.

I'm guessing `operator.iadd(x, y)` is equivalent to `z = x; z += y` only for mutable types like dictionaries and lists, but not for immutable types like numbers and strings.