# cv2.line and cv2.circle return None

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to implement the Lucas-Kanade algorithm for optical flow on Python using cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK. However, when I try to draw a line to connect the current and previous points as well as the point itself, the functions return None.

Here is the code

```
#draw the overlaying tracking img
for i,(new,old) in enumerate(zip(good_new,good_old)):
    a,b = new.ravel() #tmp new value
    c,d = old.ravel() #tmp old value

    #draws a line connecting the old point with the new point
    mask = cv2.line(mask,(a,b),(c,d),color[i].tolist(),2) #returns None... why??
    #draws the new point
    frame = cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,color[i].tolist(),-1) #returns None... why??

img = cv2.add(frame,mask)

#show on window
cv2.imshow("frame",img)
```

a,b,c,d are numpy.float32

frame is my value read from the webcam

mask is init to an array of zeros

color is a random array

This is the error message I get when I try to imshow

```
error: /Users/vagrant/pisi-64bit/tmp/opencv-2.4.5-2/work/opencv-2.4.5/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2482: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat
```

I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 11):

According to the OpenCV docs, cv2.line() and cv2.circle() always return None. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html

These methods are in place methods, so they alter the first argument that you pass to them. See this Stack Overflow question that describes these types of functions: [How are Python in-place operator functions different than the standard operator functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772987/how-are-python-in-place-operator-functions-different-than-the-standard-operator)

Your fixed code should look something like this:

```
#draw the overlaying tracking img
for i,(new,old) in enumerate(zip(good_new,good_old)):
    a,b = new.ravel() #tmp new value
    c,d = old.ravel() #tmp old value

    #draws a line connecting the old point with the new point
    cv2.line(mask,(a,b),(c,d),color[i].tolist(),2) #returns None... why??
    #draws the new point
    cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,color[i].tolist(),-1) #returns None... why??

img = cv2.add(frame,mask)
```

Comment: took me so long to figure out the bug, since it was exactly copied from opencv tutorial. they should really edit that