# The difference between x += y and x = x + y

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this python code

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x
x += [4]
>>> print(y)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So, this is because `x is y` is `True` and if I change `x`, I change `y`

But when I do:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = x
x = x + [4]
>>> print(y)
[1, 2, 3]
```

and

```
>>> id(x) == id(y)
False
```

I wonder what's the difference. I thought `x += 1` is shorthand for `x = x+1` but obviously there must be a difference.

I was even more confused, when I tried the above to strings:

```
name = 'John'
name_2 = name
name += ' Doe'

>>> print(name_2)
'John'
```

So I think the effect of `+=` depends on the object on the left, if it is mutable or not?

Comment: Yes, your explanation in the last line of your question is correct.  (Well, mostly.  It doesn't actually depend on whether it is mutable, but whether it defines `__iadd__` to actually mutate the object.  But generally mutable types will do that if they allow the operation at all.)

Comment: See [In-place Operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#inplace-operators).

Comment: @BrenBarn okay, and if I do `x = x + 'foo'` it will always create a new object, because the expression on the right side is a new object?

Comment: Related: [python: is there a difference between list.extend() and +=?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6645843)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object "on the left" handles the operator (usually, see the r-operator forms); in this case it is an [Inplace Operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#inplace-operators).

> 10.3.2. Inplace Operators
>
> Many operations have an “in-place” version. Listed below are functions providing a more primitive access to in-place operators than the usual syntax does; for example, the statement `x += y` is equivalent to `x = operator.iadd(x, y)` ..

The actual result is determined by the "x" object and *if* it handles `__iadd__` (eg. mutated as with lists) or just `__add__` (eg. a new result object, as with strings) - the selection of which protocol to use, and what value to return for the assignment, is determined by `operator.iadd` itself<sup>1</sup>.

So the shorthand of `x += y ~~ x = x + y` is *only* true for some objects - notably those that are immutable and [only] implement `__add__`.

See [How are Python in-place operator functions different than the standard operator functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772987/how-are-python-in-place-operator-functions-different-than-the-standard-operator)

---

<sup>1</sup> Semantically the operator.iadd function works about like:

```
if x.__iadd__:
    x.__iadd__(y)        # side-effect performed on x,
    return x             # returns original-but-modified object
else
    return x.__add__(y)  # return new object,
                         # __add__ should not have side-effects
```

Answer (score 0):

like @BrenBarn said, if the left hand side object is mutable it will preform an in-place operation. Otherwise a new copy will be returned, and because it was copied their id won't match anymore.

In the background it goes something analogous to this:

```
>>> import copy
>>> y = [1,2,3]
>>> x = y
>>> x+=[4]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x = copy.copy(y) #perhaps even a deepcopy()? Don't know.
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x += [5]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
class test():
    def __init__(self, ll):
        self.a = ll
    def __add__(self, other):
        return test(ll=self.a+other.a)

>>> a = test([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> a.a
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> x = test([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> x += a
>>> x.a
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> a.a
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> x.a[2][0] = 7
>>> x.a
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [7, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> a.a
[[7, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: `x = y[:] or x = y.copy()` is all that is needed, you don't need to import copy

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thnx. Did not actually know that....How about the copy vs deepcopy? I presume that if it's a native type it's jsut copy a class instance you made probably goes by deepcopy? Although I fail to understand how do they keep track of the difference then.

Comment: if you are storing other objects in the list  then you would use deepcopy as [:] or list.copy only perform a shallow copy

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I meant, how does python decide when to do a deepcopy and when a shallow one? I just tested couple of examples and it seems to do a shallow copy only... (seems a bit of a dangerous behavior though?)

Comment: It does not decide, you do. If you have other objects stored in the lists use deepcopy,  try  creating a list of lists , use `x = y[:] ` then change values in the sublists of x and see what happens. Then use deepcopy and do the same again

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm sorry I'm a bother. But I don't seem to quite understand you. Care to check out the code snippet in my edit? I mean it seems to be a dangerous behaviour to run into accidentally.

Comment: I am talking about when you decide to copy an object not  how python handles mutable vs immutable objects.