# Python Pandas Inserting into a DF Not Working

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df1

        A        Q
0   Apple    chair
1  orange     desk
2    pear  monitor
3   salad     room

df2 = df1[['Q']]

print(df2)

           Q
0      chair
1       desk
2    monitor
3       room


df2 = df2.insert(1, 'file_id_value', range(0, len(df2)))

print(df2)
```

Returns nothing, specifically, the word `'None'`. Do you know what I am doing wrong? I am not getting an error message.

Comment: `insert` is an in-place operation, which returns `None`, you are assigning `None` to your DataFrame, just remove the assignment and you will be good to go!

Comment: Even though your question has been marked as a duplicate, you may want to check the explanation to your problem given in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

```
 df2 = df2.insert(1, 'file_id_value', range(0, len(df2)))
```

Do:

```
df2.insert(1, 'file_id_value', range(0, len(df2)))
```

Explanation: in Python, everything is an object. Objects are created and saved into memory. Compared to other programming languages that do variable assignment by call-by-value, Python lets you externally modify an object without the need of saving the changes into the/a new variable (as long as the object is mutable type). For that reason you can operate into `df2` without needing to make the `insert` function return a new instance of `df2`. This does not always apply; for instance, string are non-mutable, so they need re-asignment.

To learn more, you may want to check out this SO question: [How are Python in-place operator functions different than the standard operator functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772987/how-are-python-in-place-operator-functions-different-than-the-standard-operator)

Quote for mutable objects relating the addition operator:

> An object's **iadd** method also takes two parameters, but makes the change in-place, modifying the contents of the first parameter. Because this requires object mutation, immutable types (like the standard number types) shouldn't have an **iadd** method.

Comment: It works, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome ;) @LunchBox