# Please specify what is the difference of these two line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, compiler-errors

Declaration

```
lst = []
```

What is the difference between these two lines in python why first line is working another is not

```
lst += 'a' # this line is working
lst = lst + 'a' # but this line is showing error 'can only concatenate list (not "str") to list'
```

Not understanding why this two statements are giving different results

Comment: Does this answer your question? [+ and += operators are different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027284/and-operators-are-different)

Comment: My reputation is too low to comment, but have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python) question:

Answer (score 1):

on a list `+=` is the same as `extend`. The argument is seen as an iterable. So it iterates on the string and adds it. But it's not correct in the general case, for instance a string with length > 1.

```
>>> lst = []
>>> lst += "ab"
>>> lst
['a', 'b']  # not what is expected probably
```

or adding an integer

```
>>> lst += 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

On the other hand, in `lst + <right term>`, the right term is supposed to be a list. Even a `tuple` would end up with an error.

In your case, the best solution is

```
lst += ['a']
```

or

```
lst.append('a')
```

which avoids creating a list just to add it to the first one.

As a side note,

```
lst = lst + other_list
```

is *different* from

```
lst += other_list
```

as it reassigns `lst` name on a copy of the old list with added `other_list`.

- Better be aware of that if some other variable is still referencing the old `lst`
- Plus the performance suffers from the copy of the old contents.