# What's the difference between plus and append in python for list manipulation?

Tags: python, list, append

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python append() vs. + operator on lists, why do these give different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022031/python-append-vs-operator-on-lists-why-do-these-give-different-results)

What is the actual difference between "+" and "append" for list manipulation in Python?

Answer (score 26):

There are two major differences. The first is that `+` is closer in meaning to `extend` than to `append`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a + 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    a + 4
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
>>> a + [4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a.append([4])
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, [4]]
>>> a.extend([4])
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, [4], 4]
```

The other, more prominent, difference is that the methods work in-place: `extend` is actually like `+=` - in fact, it has exactly the same behavior as `+=` except that it can accept any iterable, while `+=` can only take another list.

Comment: Is this still accurate in 2019 with Python3?

Comment: ```+= can only take another list.```

I think it can take tuples too or else how do explain being able to add to a list with ```+= 8,```

Answer (score 23):

Using `list.append` modifies the list in place - its result is `None`. Using + creates a new list.

Comment: +1, this is important because lists are mutable. Using `+` you create a new list without changing the original one, and you should know whether you intend to change the original list or not.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> L1 = [1,2,3]
>>> L2 = [97,98,99]
>>>
>>> # Mutate L1 by appending more values:
>>> L1.append(4)
>>> L1
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
>>> # Create a new list by adding L1 and L2 together
>>> L1 + L2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 97, 98, 99]
>>> # L1 and L2 are unchanged
>>> L1
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> L2
[97, 98, 99]
>>>
>>> # Mutate L2 by adding new values to it:
>>> L2 += [999]
>>> L2
[97, 98, 99, 999]
```

Answer (score 1):

`+` is a binary operator that produces a new list resulting from a concatenation of two operand lists. `append` is an instance method that appends a single element to an existing list.

P.S. Did you mean `extend`?

Answer (score 0):

The  `+` operation adds the array elements to the original array. The  `array.append` operation inserts the array (or any object) into the end of the original array.

```
[1, 2, 3] + [4, 5, 6] // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

b = [1, 2, 3]
b.append([4, 5, 6]) // [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
```

Take a look here: [Python append() vs. + operator on lists, why do these give different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022031/python-append-vs-operator-on-lists-why-do-these-give-different-results)