# count variable is not updating in recursive function call

Tags: python

The following code is finding permutation, but the `count` variable is not updating. Can anyone please point out the mistake as to why the change in `count` is not reflected.

```
def swap_arr_elems(arr, src_idx, dest_idx):
    tmp = arr[src_idx]
    arr[src_idx] = arr[dest_idx]
    arr[dest_idx] = tmp
    return

def permuate(arr, left, right, output, count):
    if left == right:
        output.append(list(arr))
        count += 1
        #count.append('1')
        return

    for i in range(left, right, 1):
        swap_arr_elems(arr, left, i)
        permuate(arr, left + 1, right, output, count)
        swap_arr_elems(arr, left, i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = 0    
    #count = []
    test_input = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    test_output = []
    permuate(test_input, 0, len(test_input), test_output, count)
    print("count : " + str(count))
    for item in test_output:
        print(item)
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
output of the above code is:
count : 0
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'c', 'b']
['b', 'a', 'c']
['b', 'c', 'a']
['c', 'b', 'a']
['c', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: Some thoughts: `permuate` is not a word; maybe you meant `permute`? A shorter (and [more efficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554130/fastest-way-to-swap-elements-in-python-list)) way to swap array elements is to use `arr[src_idx], arr[dest_idx] = arr[dest_idx], arr[src_idx]`. Finally, you could avoid the need for an `output` list by using `yield list(arr)` instead of `output.append(list(arr))`.

Comment: @ Frerich Raabe I am beginner to python and will try to understand and use yield. Thanks for pointing this .. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally name this **the mutable and non-mutable effect** don't know it's real name

**Count** is an integer. That is it is an immutable object and it's scope is within the main function so it's value is not changed

That is when you do `count+=1` a new object is created and that object is not returned

**test_output** is an List.This is a mutable object .Even though you change it's value it is changed in the same list

```
output.append(list(arr)) #adds to the same  test_output list
```

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152195/python-multiple-assignment-and-references/31153595#31153595) for more insights on mutable and non-mutable objects and behaviors

As per @brunodesthuilliers `output=output+list(arr)` changes the output .This is due to the fact `+` creates a new object see below for explanation

```
>>> out=[1,2,3]
>>> id(out)
33535760
>>> out.append(2)
>>> id(out)
33535760
>>> out=out+[3]
>>> id(out)
33535600
```

Comment: I think this explanation is more meaningful. Is there way I can make count mutable?

Comment: Any way to introspect, if the variable type is mutable or immutable?

Comment: count is already immutable wait will add a link to this saying which is mutable and which are immutable

Comment: @dearvivekkumar no you can not see the link

Comment: It actually has nothing to do with immutability but with the difference between rebinding a name and mutating an object. If the OP's code used `output = output + [list(arr)]` instead of `output.append(list(arr))`, the problem would be the same with `output`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks mate but the thing is `output = output + [list(arr)]` a new object so the result is changed  see this answer by jon in this (link )[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177533/whats-the-difference-between-plus-and-append-in-python-for-list-manipulation]

Comment: @VigneshKalai I don't think you get my point. What I say is that the OP's problem is that rebinding an argument's name in a function does not change the original object, **and that is has nothing to do with the object being mutable or not** - so if he used `output = output + [list(arr)]` instead of `output.append(list(arr))`, he would complain that `output` is not "updated" either.

Answer (score 4):

You are only increasing the `count` when `left==right` and then you are returning from it, increasing count there would not automatically increase it in the calling function, you can try returning the count and then accepting it in the function where it is called.

Example -

```
def permuate(arr, left, right, output, count):
    if left == right:
        output.append(list(arr))
        count += 1
        #count.append('1')
        return count

    for i in range(left, right, 1):
        swap_arr_elems(arr, left, i)
        count += permuate(arr, left + 1, right, output, count)
        swap_arr_elems(arr, left, i)
    return count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    count = 0    
    #count = []
    test_input = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    test_output = []
    count = permuate(test_input, 0, len(test_input), test_output, count)
    print("count : " + str(count))
    for item in test_output:
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, scope of `count` variable is only in main loop.

`count` variable in `if main` loop and count variable in `permuate` function are different.

If you want value of count variable from `permuate` function then return count value from function and accept in count variable.

**Demo:**

```
>>> count = 10
>>> def test(count):
...    count += 1
...    print "In test:", id(count)
...    return count
... 
>>> count = test(count)
In test: 149784632
>>> count 
11
```

Comment: from main I am passing 2 variables(count & test_output) to the permuatate() function. test_ouput variable is modified inside of permuate function, and the modified value is obtained inside main. But why count variable is behaving differently?

Answer (score 1):

`permuate` function is not returning any value. It is just returning the flow of control the way you wrote it. So, you must modify it to `return count`. Also, your `swap_arr_elems` function is not doing anything really because it is not returning any value. Alternatively, you could define variable `count` in `permuate` as `global`.

Comment: Basically, I am from C/C++ background and learning python. So can you please explain me the underline concept by which you are saying that return count is mandatory? In C++ call-by-reference or call-by-value, what is in python then. Or please provide me any link for understanding it

Answer (score 1):

Primitives are immutable. When you try to increment count inside your function you are switching what memory address `count` inside the function is referring to, the outside `count` is unchanged:

In CPython as an implementation detail, the `id` of an object is also the memory address so we can clearly see this happening:

```
def fn(inside_count):
    print id(inside_count), '- inside_count before increment' 
    inside_count += 1
    print id(inside_count), '- inside_count after increment'

outside_count = 1
​
print id(outside_count), '- outside_count before fn call'
fn(outside_count)
print id(outside_count), '- outside_count after fn call'
```

---

```
140536048575784 - outside_count before fn call
140536048575784 - inside_count before increment
140536048575760 - inside_count after increment
140536048575784 - outside_count after fn call
```

---

The behavior of the list object is different because you calling the append function on the object. The memory address referred to by the inside_output doesn't change, the object at the memory address is changed.

```
def fn(inside_output):
    print id(inside_output), '- inside_output before append' 
    inside_output.append('1')
    print id(inside_output), '- inside_output after append'

outside_output = []
​
print id(outside_output), '- outside_output before fn call'
fn(outside_output)
print id(outside_output), '- outside_output after fn call'
```

---

```
4389007440 - outside_output before fn call
4389007440 - inside_output before append
4389007440 - inside_output after append
4389007440 - outside_output after fn call
```

---

That being said, since you have your permutations in a list, you should just be doing:

```
print("count : " + str(len(test_output)))
```