# Confused with list assignment in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
def proc1(p):
    p.append(1)
x=[2,5]
proc1(x)
print(x)


def proc2(p):
    p=p+[1]
y=[2,5]
proc2(y)
print(y)


z=[2,5]
z=z+[1]
print(z)
```

The output of the code is:

```
[2, 5, 1]
[2, 5]
[2, 5, 1]
```

I understand why the value of `x` and `z` have become `[2,5,1]`. But I don't understand why the value of `y` remains unchanged. I thought that after running `proc2(y)`, `y` should have referred to `[2,5,1]`.

My point is, I understand that y is not **modified/mutated** to `[2,5,1]`. But y is **reassigned to a new list**, which is [2,5,1], right? Then why does y still refer to the original value? **If the value of z has changed, why not y?**

I have checked the question [What's the difference between plus and append in python for list manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177533/whats-the-difference-between-plus-and-append-in-python-for-list-manipulation), but I'm still confused.

Comment: @Grzegorz Oledzki, I checked the question that you think is a duplicate with my question. However, I think my question is a bit different from that question. What I don't understand is, if the value of z has changed, why not that of y?

Comment: [Why does assigning to my global variables not work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929777/why-does-assigning-to-my-global-variables-not-work-in-python)