# List, variable assignment and function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
def proc2(p):
    p=p+[1]
y=[2,5]
proc2(y)
print(y)


z=[2,5]
z=z+[1]
print(z)
```

The output of the code is:

```
[2, 5]
[2, 5, 1]
```

I understand that y is not *modified* to `[2,5,1]`. But, y is *reassigned to a new list*, which is `[2,5,1]`, right? Then why does y still refer to the original value? **If the value of z has changed, why not y?**

P.S. I have just asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472574/confused-with-list-assignment-in-python) which is almost the same as this one. That question has been marked as a duplicate of another question. However, I think they are a bit different. That is why I'm posting my question again. I think I must have missed something about function.

Comment: In `proc2()`, The `p` list is appended and then `p` is reassigned to the longer list. As you mentioned, this does not affect `y` which is still pointing to the shorter list. However, in your second example, `z` is actually reassigned to point to the appended list.

Comment: The value of the original list assigned to `z` actually *hasn't* changed. You're simply not referencing it any more. If you did e.g. `old_z = z` *before* `z += 1`, then printed `old_z` afterwards, you'd see that. There's no difference in behaviour.

Comment: `p=p+[1]` does not modify the list that `p` was previously referencing. It modifies the _variable_ `p` to reference a new list. Another variable, still referencing the _old_ list, will not be affected.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What you said, I have fully understood. But, after running `proc2(y)`, y should have now pointed to the new list `[2,5,1]`. Why then, when I print y, does python say y still points to `[2,5]`?

Comment: Because it does still reference the old list? Only the local variable p got reassigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> y is reassigned to a new list

No, there's only one `y = ...` assignment in your code.

What happens when your function executes is the following:

```
# implicitly: assign formal parameter name to actual argument value
p = y

# compute p + [1] => [2, 5, 1]
# assign the result to the name p
p = p + [1]

# aaaand... nothing from here on.
```

So your function computes a result (a new list), assigns the name `p` inside the function scope, and then `p` is lost as soon as the function exits.

If you don't want to write a function that *mutates* your input list, you need to return the computed value and re-assign the name `y` to see the desired effect.

```
>>> def proc2(p):
...     p = p + [1]
...     return p
... 
>>> y = [2,5]
>>> y = proc2(y)
>>> y
[2, 5, 1]
```

Note that even if you *had* an `y = ...` assignment inside your function, that name would be local to the function and the outer scope would not care:

```
>>> def proc2(y):
...     y = y + [1]
... 
>>> y = [2,5]
>>> proc2(y)
>>> y
[2, 5]
```

Finally, you *could* tell Python that you mean the global `y` inside your functions body, but that's considered poor style (definitely here and in most other cases).

```
>>> def proc2():
...     global y
...     y = y + [1]
... 
>>> y = [2,5]
>>> proc2()
>>> y
[2, 5, 1]
```

Comment: I agree with all you said, except "If you don't want to write a function that mutates your input list". Like what @jonrsharpe mentioned, the value of the original list assigned to `p`, i.e. the input list [2, 5], actually hasn't been mutated. It's just `p` got reassigned to another list [2, 5, 1]. Do you agree?

Comment: @failbetter I never claimed that your original function mutates your input list. I wanted to say that you have to return a value in order for your function to do something useful *unless* you mutate the input argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable y is not changed because you change the variable p, which is local to your function. This variable has nothing to do with y after the function ends.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Either have your function return the new list:

   ```
   def proc2(p):
       return p + [1]
   ```
2. Or, have it modify the `p` **in-place** (and optionally return it for cleaner coding):

   ```
   def proc2(p):
       p += [1]  # this is not exactly the same as p = p + [1]
       return p  # <- optional!
   ```

Your code, instead of modifying the existing `p`, it creates a new one which is however not communicated to the outer scope; and as a result *dies* when the function quits.

Answer (score 0):

To better understand what happens here, check ids of z and y, they are different, which means z and y are different objects. Changing one of them does not affect the other.

`y=[1,2]
z=[1,2]
print id(y), id(z)`