# What is the difference between path += [newpath] and path = path + [newpath] in python

Tags: python

In the function below, when I use `path = path + [start]` then I will get the result `['A', 'B', 'E']` but when I use `path += [start]` then I will get the result `['A', 'B', 'D', 'E']`. Why?

My code:

```
graph1 = {'A':['B','C'],
          'B':['A','D','E'],
          'C':['A','F'],
          'D':['B'],
          'E':['B','F'],
          'F':['C','E']}

def find_path(graph,start,end,path=[]):

    path = path + [start]

    if start == end:
        return path
    if start not in graph:
        return None

    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath = find_path(graph,node,end,path)
            if newpath:
                return newpath 
    return None

print(find_path(graph1,'A','E'))
```

Comment: `paht + [start]` creates a new list, while `+= [start]` does not. See [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) to see why that is affecting your results.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i will look over there ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

First, the `path=[]` in your definition of `find_path` is a [mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument), which has a very surprising behavior if you're not expecting it. The short version is that the default value of `path` is not a new `[]` each time, but rather *the same* `[]` every time.

Second, `path = path + [start]` *rebinds* the name `path` to a new `list` object created by the concatenation, while `path += [start]` *mutates* the existing `list` object pointed to by `path`. The best resource I can think of for learning more about this distinction is the article [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

The combination of the two means that you are mutating the *same* list each time; if you change either of them you will get separate list objects  and not see this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from usage of a mutable value as default argument in your `find_path` definition.

- When you use `path += [start]` you actually alter the default value
  of `path`
- When you use `path = path + [start]` you actually store the
  `path` argument in a local `path` variable before altering it.

more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51780924/what-is-the-difference-between-append-and-in-python/51781431#51781431)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, for lists Python overloads `+=` to mean the same as `list.extend` (in all cases rather than just when the difference is invisible), so it's going to extend the LHS with the RHS *in-place*, whereas the normal binary `+` will create a brand new list object, copy the LHS in it, then copy the RHS in it.

This is noticeable here because in Python default values are created during module parsing and bound to the function itself, you don't get a new value every time the function is invoked. So if you modify `path` in-place (which is what `+=` does) it remains between invocations of the function.