# Cannot modify item of list within for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I've found out that while executing `for` loop over list of mutable items I cannot modify that item, however I am able to modify element of that item if that element is mutable. Why?

```
# Create alist which contain mutable
alist = [[1, 2, 3],]

#1 For loop
for x in alist:
    x = x + [9,]
print alist
# let's replace alist[0] to list which contain another one and try to modify it
alist[0] = [[[1,2],3]]

print2 alist # [[[[1, 2], 3]]]
#2 For loop
for x in alist:
    x[0] = x[0] + [9,]
# list modified ...
print alist # [[[[1, 2], 3, 9]]], Modified !
```

I am aware that modifying list which you are iterating on isn't good practice (it's better to iterate over copy of it), so please don't point me to that moment.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022031/python-append-vs-operator-on-lists-why-do-these-give-different-results.

Comment: @AKS thanks, will take a look on it

Answer (score 0):

The reason of such behaviour is that while performing **for loop #1** new list is produced by applying `+` operator to list( it can be tracked by getting  [id](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) of `x`).

However in **for loop #2** by access element of item with index `x[0]` object which already in memory is being modified. It can be easily found by calling [id](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) on x while iterating over `alist`

```
# Create alist which contain mutable
alist = [[1, 2, 3],]

#1 for loop
for x in alist:
    print id(x), id(alist[0]), 'Same?:', id(x) == id(alist[0]) 
    # id(x): 4425690360 id(alist[0]) 4425690360 Same?: True
    x = x + [9,]
    print id(x), id(alist[0]), 'Same?:', id(x) == id(alist[0]) 
    # id(x): 4425770696 id(alist[0]) 4425690360 Same?: False
# mutable item not modified, so my guess is that x actually are copy of that item
print alist # [[1, 2, 3]]
# let's replace alist[0] to list which contain another one and try to modify it
alist[0] = [[[1,2],3]]

print alist
#2 for loop
for x in alist:
    print id(x), id(alist[0]), 'Same?:', id(x) == id(alist[0]) 
    # id(x): 4425811008 id(alist[0]) 4425811008 Same?: True

    x[0] = x[0] + [9,]
    print id(x), id(alist[0]), 'Same?:', id(x) == id(alist[0])
    # id(x): 4425811008 id(alist[0]) 4425811008 Same?: True
# list modified ...
print alist # [[[[1, 2], 3, 9]]]
```

To solve problem use [array.append](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#array.array.append) to modify item within for loop, see sample below:

```
alist = [[1, 2, 3],]
for x in alist:
    print id(x), id(alist[0]), 'Same?:', id(x) == id(alist[0])
    x.append(9)
    print id(x), id(alist[0]), 'Same?:', id(x) == id(alist[0])
# list modified ...
print alist # [[1, 2, 3, 9],]
```