# Django bulk_create a list of lists

Tags: python, django

As the title indicates, is there a way to bulk_create list of lists. Like right now I bulk_create it like -

```
for i in range(len(x))   
  arr1 = []
    for m in range(len(y)):
    arr1.append(DataModel(foundation=foundation, date=dates[m], price=price[m]))
  DataModel.objects.bulk_create(arr1)
```

Now this will bulk create till the length of x.

Can it be done like so -

```
arr = []
for i in range(len(x))   
  arr1 = []
    for m in range(len(y)):
    arr1.append(DataModel(foundation=foundation, date=dates[m], price=price[m]))
  arr.append(arr1)
DataModel.objects.bulk_create(arr)
```

If not, what else can be done to store data faster?

Answer (score 0):

Append your object to `arr`, not `arr1`.
Or you can make flat list before `bulk_create`:

```
import itertools
arr = list(itertools.chain(*arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
arr = []
for i in range(len(x))   
  arr1 = []
    for m in range(len(y)):
    arr1.append(DataModel(foundation=foundation, date=dates[m], price=price[m]))
  #instead of appending the list, add list together to make one
  arr = arr + arr1
DataModel.objects.bulk_create(arr)
```

this will produce a single list of items process-able by `bulk_create()` method

reference: [Python append() vs. + operator on lists, why do these give different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022031/python-append-vs-operator-on-lists-why-do-these-give-different-results)