# How to transpose a 2D list array using loops in python?

Tags: python, list, 2d, transpose

Say I have:

```
a = [[1, 1, 1, 6], [0, 2, -1, 3], [4, 0, 10, 42]]
```

and I want to transpose it to:

```
a = [[1,0,4], [1,2,0], [1,-1,10], [6,3,42]]
```

using loops in python. The current code that I have is:

```
def transpose(a):
    s = []
    for row in range(len(a)):
        for col in range(len(a)):
            s = s + [a[col][row]]
return s
```

But this gives me the output of:

```
[1, 0, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, -1, 10]
```

Instead of this:

```
[[1,0,4], [1,2,0], [1,-1,10], [6,3,42]]
```

Can anyone help me? I'm still new at this stuff and don't understand why it doesn't work. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
>>> a = [[1, 1, 1, 6], [0, 2, -1, 3], [4, 0, 10, 42]]
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(*a)]
[[1, 0, 4], [1, 2, 0], [1, -1, 10], [6, 3, 42]]
```

`zip(*a)` unpacks the three sub-lists in `a` and combines them element by element. Meaning, the first elements of the each of the three sub-lists are combined together, the second elements are combined together and so on. But `zip()` returns tuples instead of lists like you want in your output. Like this:

```
>>> zip(*a)
[(1, 0, 4), (1, 2, 0), (1, -1, 10), (6, 3, 42)]
```

`[list(x) for x in zip(*a)]` converts each of the tuples to lists giving the output the way you need it.

Comment: I know that's one way to do it, but is there another way to do this using for loops or while loops?

Comment: The other answer addresses your question. You are seeing one list in your output because you aren't creating a list in the inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that is based on your code:

```
def transpose(a):
    s = []
    # We need to assume that each inner list has the same size for this to work
    size = len(a[0])
    for col in range(size):
        inner = []
        for row in range(len(a)):
            inner.append(a[row][col])
        s.append(inner)
    return s
```

If you define an inner list for the inner loop, your output is this:

```
[[1, 0, 4], [1, 2, 0], [1, -1, 10], [6, 3, 42]]
```

Comment: Instead of inner.append and s.append, inner = inner + [a[row][col]] and s = s + [inner] works the same way! Thank you!!

Comment: I wouldn't say that it works *exactly* the same way - you might want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022031/python-append-vs-operator-on-lists-why-do-these-give-different-results/2022044#2022044) helpful answer that explains the differences.

Comment: @Catury: It does not work the same way. When you do `list = list + [l]`, it creates a new list  with the value of `list` and `l`, and assign new list to `list`. where as `list.append(l)` appends `l` to existing `list` list

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution without any fancy function. You may achieve it using *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> a = [[1, 1, 1, 6], [0, 2, -1, 3], [4, 0, 10, 42]]
>>> sublist_size = len(a[0])
>>> [[item[i] for item in a] for i in range(sublist_size)]
[[1, 0, 4], [1, 2, 0], [1, -1, 10], [6, 3, 42]]
```

However, simplest way is by using `zip()`:

```
>>> list(zip(*a))  # for Python 3, OR, just zip(*a) in Python 2 
[(1, 0, 4), (1, 2, 0), (1, -1, 10), (6, 3, 42)]
```

Comment: Slightly shorter   b = [[i[j] for i in a] for j in range(len(a)+1)]

Comment: @JackTheCrab: It is not necessary that sublist's length will be 1 more that the list's length (even though in this example). So `range(len(a[0]))` should be used instead of `range(len(a) + 1)`. By nesting the two steps and shortening the variable name to decrease one line of code; It is not good practice. Shorter is not always good. If bigger (to very little extent) code is more readable, go for bigger ;)

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing it out. Definetely agree on readability as well;)