# How do I concatenate strings from input()?

Tags: python-3.x, input, split, concatenation, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to create a game of naughts and crosses. In order to prevent the same move being made more than once, I have made a `move_log` variable, `move_log = []`, which logs all moves and an error message which makes the player aware that they need to select a new move to proceed, this is to happen if their initial move is `in` the `move_log`. After each move, I have written the following to update the `move_log`:

```
move_log = []

.........

move_log += player_move
```

and

```
move_log = []

.........

move_log += pc_move
```

The available moves are `'tl', 'tm', 'tr', 'ml', 'm', 'mr', 'bl', 'bm'`or`'br'`

My problem is that, once in the list of the `move_log` variable, this is the list:

```
['b', 'r'] # example of list after 1st move
```

This will make my `if` statement somewhat tricky, any suggestions? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using append instead of the += operator. They have different behaviour as described in the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022031/python-append-vs-operator-on-lists-why-do-these-give-different-results)

```
move_log.append(pc_move)
```

Here's an example:
https://repl.it/repls/ImpassionedSwiftTrust

Comment: Fantastic! Much appreciated!

Comment: Pleasure to help :) @LeoGER