# why python list behave like this ? why not it doesn't add "de" to the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, operators

Please explain why this code behave like this.

```
x=["a","b","c"]
x+="de"
print (x)

output := ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

why it out like above output ? why not it doesn't output like the below lines ?.i know that we can append the "de" to output like this.how the "+" operators works in list ?

```
output := ['a', 'b', 'c', 'de']
```

Comment: `+=` on a list adds a sequence of items. `"de"` is a sequence of two items, `'d'` and `'e'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python append() vs. + operator on lists, why do these give different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022031/python-append-vs-operator-on-lists-why-do-these-give-different-results)

Comment: Thank you, sir :-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @khelwood's reaction: if you would like to add 'de' using `+=`, you can do it like this:

```
x = ["a","b","c"]
x += ["de"]
print(x)
```