# How to make a nested FOR loop of distance between points and save coordinates if distance is less than 5?

Tags: python, arrays

Given 2 arrays, I want to compare the coordinates of array1 with array2 and print the coordinates if the distance is <= 5.
I used the code below, but it is not printing the correct coordinates.

```
def euclideanDistance(coordinate1, coordinate2):
    dist= pow(pow(coordinate1[0] - coordinate2[0], 2) + pow(coordinate1[1] - coordinate2[1], 2), .5)
    if dist <= 5:
        return (coordinate1, coordinate2)

coords= [[17, 268],[17, 396],[18, 243], [18, 548]]
coords1= [[16, 484],[17, 398],[17, 640],[18, 331]]
distances = []
for i in range(len(coords)-1):
    for j in range(i, len(coords1)):
        distances += [euclideanDistance(coords[i],coords1[j])]
        print(distances)
```

The output should be: [17, 396], [17, 398]

Comment: Please add expected output and actual output to your question

Comment: coords= [[ 17 268],[ 17 396],[ 18 243], [ 18 548]]

coords1= [[ 16 484],[ 17 398],[ 17 640],[ 18 331]]
Output should be [ 17 396], [ 17 398]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the function `euclideanDistance` only returns the coordinates if the distance is larger than 5. Therefore, because you add the result of the function to the array `distances`, you add a tuple of `None, None` when the distance is smaller than 5.
Therefore, I would return `False` or any other flag in order to indicate that the `dist` is not smaller or equal to 5.

Secondly, I don't follow the logic of your `for` loops - why is the nested for loop only running in the range between `i` and the length of `coords1`?

Thirdly, variable names should be meaningful.

Also, you can check out the difference between `append()` and the `+` operation on arrays [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022031/python-append-vs-operator-on-lists-why-do-these-give-different-results).

Therefore I would change the code to:

```
def euclideanDistance(coordinate1, coordinate2):
    dist = pow(pow(coordinate1[0] - coordinate2[0], 2) + pow(coordinate1[1] - 
coordinate2[1], 2), .5)
    if dist <= 5:
        return (coordinate1, coordinate2)
    return False


distances = []
first_cords= [[17, 268],[17, 396],[18, 243], [18, 548]]
second_cords= [[16, 484],[17, 398],[17, 640],[18, 331]]
for f_cord in first_cords:
    for s_cord in second_cords:
        if euclideanDistance(f_cord,s_cord) is not False:
            distances.append([f_cor,s_cord])
print(distances)
```

Which prints: `[[[17, 396], [17, 398]]]`.

Comment: please see my edit in question. i need to use the filtered coordinate values further. how can i access new x-coordinate only. how can I print all xcoordinates of new array?

Comment: Don't change the question to a different question after your original question has been answered. Please post a new question.