# difference between += and append() in Python

Tags: python, append

When I use the += in my function, I get this error:  UnboundLocalError: local variable 'travel_log' referenced before assignment
but it totally works with the append() function.
What is the difference?

```
travel_log = []
def add_new_country(countries_visited, times_visited, cities_visited):
    new_country = {}
    new_country["country"] = countries_visited
    travel_log += new_country
```

Comment: because `+=` involves a `global` var assignment in this case

Comment: New to coding :) 
Would you please explain more?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2022044/17184842 Detailed answer on the same question.

Comment: Any assignment *anywhere* in a function marks the variable as *local* by the compiler. `+=` involves an assignment to `travel_log`, but *there is no local variable defined prior to that line*

Answer (score 2):

Because you assigned to `travel_log` in your `add_new_country` function (`+=` is an assignment), it is considered a local variable in that function. Because it is a local variable, and you never assigned it a value, `travel_log` has no value when you attempt to `+=` to it. Python does not fall back to using the global variable of the same name.

This is somewhat surprising because the `+=` operation on a list is equivalent to calling its `extend()` method, and the name remains bound to the same list. The error feels more reasonable when the variable is a number or some other immutable object. But it's the same behavior.

If you want to operate on the global variable, say so:

```
def add_new_country(countries_visited, times_visited, cities_visited):
    global travel_log
    # etc.
```

But it's better to use `travel_log.append()`. Appending isn't an assignment, so it doesn't make `travel_log` local.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you make an assignment to a variable in a scope, that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any similarly named variable in the outer scope. Since the last statement in `add_new_country()` assigns a new value to `travel_log`, the compiler recognizes it as a local variable.

In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be local unless explicitly declared as global.

So in your case, declare `travel_log` as global scope inside the function

```
travel_log = []

def add_new_country(countries_visited, times_visited, cities_visited):
    # now function will refer the globally declared variable
    global travel_log
    new_country = {}
    new_country["country"] = countries_visited
    travel_log += new_country
```

Checkout this blog for a detailed explanation: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value