# Why is single-value tuple plus list is more efficient than appending a number?

Tags: python, list, performance, tuples

Assume we need to append single number `1` to array `a`.

In Python we have 5 obvious ways:

1. `a.append(1)`
2. `a += [1]`
3. `a += 1,`
4. `a.extend((1,))`
5. `a.extend([1])`

Let's measure it with `timeit` :

```py
from timeit import timeit

print(timeit("a.append(1)", "a = []", number=10_000_000))
print(timeit("a += [1]", "a = []", number=10_000_000))
print(timeit("a += 1,", "a = []", number=10_000_000))
print(timeit("a.extend((1,))", "a = []", number=10_000_000))
print(timeit("a.extend([1])", "a = []", number=10_000_000))
```

Here is the console's output:

```
5.05412472199896
5.869792026000141
3.1280645619990537
4.988895307998973
8.05588494499898
```

Why is third one more efficient than others?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022031/python-append-vs-operator-on-lists-why-do-these-give-different-results

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki He's not getting different results, just different performance.

Comment: Probably because tuples are simpler than lists, since they're immutable. So creating the tuple is faster.

Comment: But why creating tuple and plusing it to list is more efficient than just appending value, it is not that simple

Comment: Your tests aren't just timing adding to the list, they're also timing creating the tuple or list that you extend with.

Comment: I suggest you look at the generated bytecode to see the difference.

Comment: Well the first thing I would say is that you can't add an `int` to a `list`. So the `a += 1` actually crashes.

Comment: Yes, and this is the part of the question, creating tuple is not free, but it is still better

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide it's `a += 1,` (note the trailing comma that makes it a tuple).  I missed it on the first reading too.  :)

Comment: I am not adding int, i am adding (int, )

Comment: Oh its a tuple without the parentheses.

Comment: @Barmar it's actually cached by the compiler, a tuple literal that only consists of immutable literals becomes a constant

Comment: Note `+=` with an array does not `append()` nor is it the same implementation as `+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The creation of a tuple `(1,)` is optimized away by the compiler. On the other hand, the list is always created. Look at `dis.dis`

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('a.extend((1,))')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (extend)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1,))
              6 CALL_METHOD              1
              8 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('a.extend([1])')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (extend)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              6 BUILD_LIST               1
              8 CALL_METHOD              1
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Notice, it takes less byte-code instructions, and merely does a `LOAD_CONST` on `(1,)`. On the other hand, for the list, `BUILD_LIST` is called (with a `LOAD_CONST` for `1`).

Note, you can access these constants on the code object:

```
>>> code = compile('a.extend((1,))', '', 'eval')
>>> code
<code object <module> at 0x10e91e0e0, file "", line 1>
>>> code.co_consts
((1,),)
```

Finally, as to why `+=` is faster than `.extend`, well, again if you look at the bytecode:

```
>>> dis.dis('a += b')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              4 INPLACE_ADD
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis('a.extend(b)')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (extend)
              4 LOAD_NAME                2 (b)
              6 CALL_METHOD              1
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

You'll notice for `.extend`, it that requires *first* resolving the method (which takes extra time). Using the operator on the other hand has it's own bytecode: `INPLACE_ADD` so everything is pushed down into that C layer (plus, magic methods skip instance namespaces and a bunch of hooplah and are looked up directly on the class).

Comment: But what about `a.append(1)`? Why isn't that faster, since it doesn't have to create a tuple or list?

Comment: Note that you should be calling `extend` in these examples, not `append`, although it doesn't make a difference for the point you're making.

Comment: @Barmar look at the edit. Using operators is faster than using methods. Also, yeah you are right about extend

Comment: Doesn't `INPLACE_ADD` have to look up and call the `__iadd__` method?

Comment: @Barmar it does,but without hopping back to the bytecode evaluation loop, done entirely in C, and it skips the instance namespace since magic-method lookups are special-cased

Comment: Yeah, I was about to conjecture that there are optimizations for the built-in types.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to sum up, what @juanpa.arrivillaga, @Samwise and @Barmar mentioned:

`a += (1, )` is equiualent to `a.__iadd__((1, ))` but without loading methods. If we look at `dis`:

```py
>>> dis.dis("a.__iadd__((1,))")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (__iadd__)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1,))
              6 CALL_METHOD              1
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

```py
>>> dis.dis("a += (1, )")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1,))
              4 INPLACE_ADD
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

```py
>>> dis.dis("a.append(1)")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (append)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              6 CALL_METHOD              1
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see that in first and third cases we needed to use `LOAD_METHOD` before call and this is most resourse-mean part, whilst `+=` have direct disassembler

Btw, first case is more worse than previous five and got `8.292503296999712` on timeit

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the tuple and list is entirely due to the difference in how much time it takes to create each.  This is easy to verify by timing the list/tuple creation on its own, and by timing the `+=` operation independently of the creation of the objects being added:

```
>>> timeit("b = [1]", number=10_000_000)
0.447727799997665
>>> timeit("b = (1,)", number=10_000_000)
0.17419059993699193
>>> timeit("a += b", "a, b = [], [1]", number=10_000_000)
0.5244328000117093
>>> timeit("a += b", "a, b = [], (1,)", number=10_000_000)
0.5320590999908745
```

Comment: I would be mostly curious why `a.append(1)` is not faster than both.

Comment: That's harder to answer without going into the guts of CPython, but I'd imagine that `+=` is able to optimize away an attribute lookup or otherwise bypass some piece of Python interpreter logic that makes `.append` take longer.

Comment: Another possibility is that mutating a small list takes longer than creating an entirely new one and rebinding a variable...

Comment: I think @juanpa.arrivillaga in the other answer has a pretty good hypothesis.

Comment: ah yes, that's the "attribute lookup" I was referring to.  My first hunch was exactly right.  :)