# rearranging list using for loop and random choice

Tags: python, for-loop, random

```py
import random
a=['sai','raju','phani'] 
b=[]
for I in a:
     b += random.Choice(a) 
print(b)
```

result:

> ['s', 'a', 'i', 's', 'a', 'i', 'r', 'a', 'j', 'u']

but expected to be total string not individual

> ['sai','sai','raju']

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) and pass in the number of samples for `b` in the argument `k`.

```
import random
a=['sai','raju','phani']
b=[]

b = random.choices(a, k=len(a))

print(b)
```

EDIT: if you want it in a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    b.append(random.choice(a))
```

Comment: want in for loop

Comment: i want do in for loop any idea

Comment: cant we do with operator using b+=random.choice(a) ??

Comment: Nope, you need to use `append`. Check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022031/python-append-vs-operator-on-lists-why-do-these-give-different-results).