# Python list appending

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Python, what is the difference between “.append()” and “+= []”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725782/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-append-and)

In Python, I've recently noticed that you can append list items in two ways:

```
a.append(1)
a += [1]
```

I like using the second approach because it is more readable for me. Are there any downsides to using it?

Comment: I'd say the second is more error-prone. Are you adding the number `1` or the list `[1]`? `.append()` and `.extend()` make this distiction clear, while also not requiring the confusing extraneous brackets.

Comment: AFAICT, the bracket notation is identical to `a.extend([1])`, which acts just like `a.append(1)`. The only downside is that the second approach is about twice as slow.

Comment: But `.append()` and `.extend()` are even easier to confuse. Personally I find `+= [1]` absolutely clear. It's whatever you're used to, I guess...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those two methods aren't quite equivalent. The `+=` method:

```
a += [1]
```

requires that you first create a *new* list containing the single element `1`, tack it on to the list `a`, then discard the single-element list. This would be more equivalent to:

```
a.extend([1])
```

You will likely find that `a.append(1)` does less work, since it does not need to create a single-element list which it's just going to throw away in the next step.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the interesting results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/725882/589206). Short version: append is faster.

Comment: Didn't know what to search for, thanks. Can you flag my question as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Python implementation, but `append` will never be slower than the second variant.

`a += [1]` creates a temporary list with one element. Additionally, the `+=` operator has to perform some extra work to determine the size of the new list. A good Python implementation may reduce the overhead by not actually constructing the list `[1]` in memory.

As with virtually every performance question, it doesn't matter unless your code is really performance-critical. With cpython 2.7, I measured the following values:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('l = []\nfor i in range(200):\n\tl.append(1)\n')
27.95561385154724
>>> timeit.timeit('l = []\nfor i in range(200):\n\tl += [1]\n')
37.52841401100159
```