# Aesthetic way of appending to a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, syntax, append

When appending longer statements to a list, I feel `append` becomes awkward to read. I would like a method that would work for dynamic list creation (i.e. don't need to initialize with zeros first, etc.), but I cannot seem to come up with another way of doing what I want.

**Example:**

```
import math
mylist = list()
phi = [1,2,3,4] # lets pretend this is of unknown/varying lengths
i, num, radius = 0, 4, 6

while i < num:
    mylist.append(2*math.pi*radius*math.cos(phi[i]))
    i = i + 1
```

Though `append` works just fine, I feel it is less clear than:

```
mylist[i] = 2*math.pi*radius*math.cos(phi[i])
```

But this does not work, as that element does not exist in the list yet, yielding:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I *could* just assign the resulting value to temporary variable, and append that, but that seems ugly and inefficient.

Comment: you could wrap the original `__setitem__` operator and write one that checks for boundaries and calls `append` as needed.

Comment: I will certainly look into this; though, I am not immediately familiar how to do it. An example would be greatly appreciated, if you have the time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case you could use a list comprehension:

```
mylist = [2*math.pi*radius*math.cos(phi[i]) for i in range(num)]
```

Or, if you're doing this sort of computations a lot, you could move away from using lists and use [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) instead:

```
In [78]: import numpy as np

In [79]: phi = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [80]: radius = 6

In [81]: 2 * np.pi * radius * np.cos(phi)
Out[81]: array([ 20.36891706, -15.68836613, -37.32183785, -24.64178397])
```

I find this last version to be the most aesthetically pleasing of all. For longer `phi` it will also be more performant than using lists.

Comment: This looks great, and definitely the direction I would like to go in. I'm only briefly familiar with numpy, so I tend to think only in terms of standard library stuff.

Answer (score 12):

You don;t need an existing list and append to it later. Just use list comprehension

List comprehension,

- is fast,
- easy to comprehend,
- and can easily be ported as a generator expression

  ```
  >>> import math
  >>> phi = [1,2,3,4]
  >>> i, num, radius = 0, 4, 6
  >>> circum = 2*math.pi*radius
  >>> mylist = [circum * math.cos(p) for p in phi]
  ```

Reviewing your code, here are some generic suggestions

- Do not compute a known constant in an iteration

  ```
  while i < num:
      mylist.append(2*math.pi*radius*math.cos(phi[i]))
      i = i + 1
  ```

should be written as

```
circum = 2*math.pi
while i < num:
    mylist.append(circum*math.cos(phi[i]))
    i = i + 1
```

- Instead of `while` use `for-each` construct

  ```
  for p in phi:
      mylist.append(circum*math.cos(p))
  ```
- If an expression is not readable, break it into multiple statements, after all readability counts in Python.

Comment: Or even iterate through `phi` directly in the list comp.

Comment: Excellent suggestions. Thanks! In terms of readability for this particular example, I like the idea of having the statement together as it would read "two pi r, times the cosine of phi" to me. That way when I'm looking at the code I can immediately see it is calculating the circumference of a circle. This was my "problem" with my use of append, as it obfuscates that when reading the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist += [2*math.pi*radius*math.cos(phi[i])]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use list concatenation, but append is twice as fast according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725782/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-append-and):

```
import math
mylist = list()
phi = [1,2,3,4] # lets pretend this is of unknown/varying lengths
i, num, radius = 0, 4, 6

while i < num:
    mylist += [(2*math.pi*radius*math.cos(phi[i]))]
    i = i + 1
```