# Iterating through multiple lists with same index position in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and I was just trying some list manipulations. I have three lists

```
A = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
B = [22,44,66,88,12,10]
C = [2,4,6,8,10,20]
```

I want to iterate over these three lists and for each value of C I want to add half of that value to the corresponding values of A and B. 
For example for the 1st iteration - 
half = 2/2= 1
So A = 10 + 1 and B = 22+1
So the final lists should look something like this

```
A = [11,22,33,44,55,70]
B = [23,46,69,92,17,20]
C = [2,4,6,8,10,20]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the lists all have the same lengths, you can iterate with [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=built%20functions#enumerate) function:

```
for i, n in enumerate(C):
    A[i] += n/2
    B[i] += n/2

>>> A
[11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 70]
>>> B
[23, 46, 69, 92, 17, 20]
```

Comment: Nice, but remember if you're on Python 2 you might get surprising results with `n / 2`. Do `n / 2.` or put `from __future__ import division` at the top of the script. If on Python 3, disregard this comment.

Comment: @mwaskom Good point, that will depend on what does the OP wants. If he wants to keep the division integer then n/2 will do ok, if not, in Python2 he can always do `n/2.` to get `float` result. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> A, B = zip(*((a + c/2, b + c/2) for a, b, c in zip(A, B, C)))
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Dang you. :D

Comment: +1 I like oneliners but remember, _Simple is better than complex_. :)

Comment: A one-line solution like this isn't really useful for learning or for practical use; according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/725818/1577850 using `+` for two lists will tell Python to make a new copy of `A` and `B` which is not what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

ITs best to use `Numpy` arrays.

```
import numpy as np
A, B, C = map(np.array, [A, B, C])
A, B = A - C/2, B - C/2
```