# Python algorithm for converting an integer to binary: questions about efficiency

Tags: python, algorithm, list, binary, string-concatenation

I made a simple algorithm for converting an integer into binary, and returning the binary as a string. Currently the bits are added to the front of a list. Would it be more efficient (in terms of either time or space) to concatenate strings at each step instead of appending to a list? Why/why not?

```
def toBinary(n):
    l = []
    while n > 0:
        bit = n%2
        n = math.floor(n/2)
        l = [bit]+l
    return ''.join(map(str,l))
```

I know an easier way to do the exact same thing would be to use:

```
bin(10)[2:]
```

(with the slice just taking off the prefix) but I wanted to try implementing the algorithm myself.

[edit] I see that `append()` is more efficient than simple concatenation (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725782/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-append-and)). What about appending at each step and then reversing the list? Or is there a similarly efficient function for adding to the beginning of the list (like `insert()`)?

Comment: `format(n, 'b')` would be more concise still.

Comment: That is nice, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When building a string from disparate characters, using a list then `str.join()` is faster than appending to a string. The latter has to build a new string object for each character.

That said, you can improve on your version by using bit shifting and bit masking:

```
def toBinary(n):
    l = []
    while n:
        l.append(n & 1)
        n >>= 1
    return ''.join(map(str, reversed(l)))
```

This still builds up the bits one by one from least significant to most, but *appends* rather than prepends to the list. We then simply reverse the list at the end.

- `&` here is the [binary AND operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations); it masks the value of `n` to just the least significant bit.
- `>>=` is the [augmented assignment](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) version of the [`>>` right bit shift operation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations); here it shifts the bits of `n` one step to the right, dropping the least significant bit.

Of course, the most efficient way to convert an integer to binary in Python is to not do it in Python. The built-in `bin()` function is nice, but the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) is nicest, as it lets you specify wether or not to include the `0b` prefix, and specific the number of digits to display:

```
>>> format(10, 'b')
'1010'
>>> format(10, '#b')
'0b1010'
>>> format(10, '08b')
'00001010'
>>> format(10, '#010b')
'0b00001010'
```

Answer (score 1):

[strings are immutable objects in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-are-python-strings-immutable) therefore in your example, if you were to concatenate strings, it has to be recreated for each step in the while loop - which means that it's only going to be less optimal than using a list.

Answer (score 1):

The speed difference would be so miniscule that it really wouldn't matter, but in general using `list.append()` is faster than using `list = [bit] + list`, and using `''.join(list)` is faster than concatenation.

[Here's a reference for that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join)