# Functions and Mutable lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

sorry I'm new to python and still trying to wrap my head around few fundamentals. I know lists are mutable objects in python, but can't understand how the two functions below handle lists, and why one changes the list itself and the other doesn't

```
def f(x, y):
    x.append(x.pop(0))
    x.append(y[0])
    return x

>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=[1,2]
>>> f(a,b)
>>> [2, 3, 1, 1]
>>> a
>>> [2, 3, 1, 1]

def f(x, y):
    y = y + [x]
    return y

>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> f(4,a)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a
>>> [1, 2, 3]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, the difference is in the function of `append` and `+`. `append` adds a new item to the list without creating a new list. `+` merges two lists together and creates a new list.

For more information, see [DNS's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/725818/3223917).

Comment: Thanks for that "Hayley Guillou, the answer you referred to was a great demonstration too. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

The `+` operation stores the result in a new list, while `append` operation appends the new value into the existing list

For example,

```
def f(x, y):
    y = y + [x]
    print(y)
    y.append(x)
    print(y)

a=[1,2,3]
f(4,a)
print(a)
```

gives

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3]
```

`y = y + [x]` creates a new list `y` & hence the change is not reflected to the original list `a` & also the later `append` changes the new list `y`

but

```
def f(x, y):
    y.append(x)
    print(y)
    y = y + [x]
    print(y)

a=[1,2,3]
f(4,a)
print(a)
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Here the `append` operation changes the original list `a` after that new list `y` is created