# Why can't I add a found prime, to a list of primes?

Tags: python

I'm trying to just print out the found primes. I want to add to the prime[], but I get a TypeError

```
line 63, in isprime
    primes += n
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The code:

```
def isprime(n):
    primes = []
    if n == 1:
        print '1 is special'
        return False
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n%x == 0:
            print '{} equals {} x {}'.format(n, x, n // x)
            return False
    else:
        primes += n
        print (n, "is a prime number")
        return True

for n in range(1, 1000):
    isprime(n)
```

Comment: maybe try `primes.append(n)`

Comment: There are some important differences between `.append()` and `+= []`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725782/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-append-and Also, because `.append` is a method you can use it in a function to mutate a global list, you can't do that with `+=` unless you declare the list to be  global.

Comment: FWIW, there are a couple of things you can do to make your prime test much more efficient. Note that there's not much point saving your primes like that, since the `primes` list will get cleared every time you call the function. However, there are a few ways that you can cache `n` so that you don't need to check the same number twice during a given run of the program.

Answer (score 4):

`+=` on a `list` is intended to concatenate one `list` to another. If you want to add a single element onto the end of the `list`, you can either do the straightforward:

```
primes.append(n)
```

or make a temporary `list` to allow the list concatenation operation to work (this approach is slower, and only trivially more concise, with greater memory churn involved; I highly recommend using `.append` unless you need to add more than one element at a time, in which case the `+=` approach scales better for multielement list literals):

```
primes += [n]
```

Comment: You should maybe also mention `.extend`.

Comment: @PM2Ring: I suppose. `+=` and `extend` are identical in effect (and unlike with other types like `set`, there is no difference in type strictness; you can use either one with arbitrary iterables, where `set` operator overloads limit themselves to working with `set`/`frozenset`, not arbitrary iterables). `extend` is slightly slower in CPython as a consequence of the Python function call machinery getting invoked, where syntax based `+=` avoids it. Only real benefit to `extend` is that it doesn't involve assignment, so you can use it on globals without creating locals, or on lists inside tuples.

Answer (score 0):

`primes` is a list, so to add `n`, which is an `int`, to it, you have to use the `append` method. Replace `primes += n` with `primes.append(n)`.