# Python List Comprehension with two parameters

Tags: python, list

I dont know how the i and j interact in the following code:
If i runs into result 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 but how j runs in this situation.

`noprimes = [j for i in range(2, 8) for j in range(i*2, 100, i)]`

Answer (score 2):

It is saying:

```
for i in range(2, 8):
    for j in range(i*2, 100, i):
        noprimes.append(j)
```

So first it will loop through every number from 2 - 8. For each of these numbers, `j` will be equal to a number in `(i*2, 100, i); (4, 100, 2)` <--- this is just the first iteration. The `i` signifies the starting range number as well as the step for each loop. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

*First*, avoiding codegolfing, let us reformulate the code as follows:

```
noprimes = []
for i in range(2, 8):
    for j in range(i*2, 100, i):
        noprimes += [j]
```

Note that the variable `i` is comprised between `2` **in**cluded and `8` **ex**cluded. Which means that if you want to work with `8` as included upper bound, your `range` function must be rewritten as `range(2, 8+1)`. In what follows, I assume that you do want `7` as **in**cluded upper bound. Furthermore, note that the invisible default parameter here is the step parameter of `1`, meaning that `range(2, 8)` is implicitly `range(2, 8, 1)`.

*Second*, let us see what is going on by turning this two-levels loop into multiple decomposed one-level ones.

Starting with `i=2` such that

```
i = 2
for j in range(i*2, 100, i):
    noprimes += [j]
```

is actually equivalent to

```
for j in range(2*2, 100, 2):
    noprimes += [j]
```

Above we make `j` be comprised between `4` **in**cluded and `100` **ex**cluded (`98` **in**cluded) by step of `2`.

Identically, for, say, `i=3`, we have

```
for j in range(3*2, 100, 3):
    noprimes += [j]
```

which makes `j` be comprised between `6` **in**cluded and `100` **ex**cluded by step of `3`. And given that `100` is not an integer multiple of `3`, the **in**cluded upper bound will be `99`. (Indeed, since `100%3` is equal to `1`).

And so on up to `7` **in**cluded. Which in this case would lead to

```
for j in range(14, 100, 7):
    noprimes += [j]
```

which makes `j` be comprised between `14` **in**cluded and `100` **ex**cluded by step of `7`. And given that, as before in the case of `3`, `100` is not an integer multiple of `7`, the **included** upper bound will be `100 - 100%7`, *i.e.* `98`.

---

*Additionally*, in case you wonder, with `blabla = []`, about the use of

```
blabla.append('string stuf')
```

instead of

```
blabla  += ['string stuf']
```

or even

```
blabla.extend(['string stuf'])
```

note that in this case these 3 approaches, although **not the same** things, **do the same** thing. For details about which one to chose, see

> [append vs. extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/append-vs-extend)

or

> [What is the difference between “.append()” and “+=[]”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725782/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-append-and)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted uses [List Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/). It's a neater way to write:

```
noprimes = []
for i in range(2, 8):
    for j in range(i*2, 100, i):
        noprimes.append(j)
```