# Difference between .append() and += in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, append

I'm working on LeetCode 78. Subsets and found this interesting error. If I change the marked line to the commented line, such an error will be thrown out.

[image: My function]

I announced "res" in the outer function, why is res.append() different from res += ? I know += is more like .extend() but that is not the conflict here. What caused the reference error?

Comment: This ia a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725782/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-append-and

Comment: @dir No it is not. So the answer to your question: `.append()` will mutate the existing object `res` is pointing to while `+=` will create a new, local variable named `res`. That's why you are getting the error because Python thinks that (the second) `res` is a local variable, but you can't `+=` to it because it hasn't been assigned before within that function.

Comment: Interesting. If you have both of them together, then `append` starts to throw error too.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will throw an error. `+=1` only applies to One number, whether it being an integer or a float or a decimal. The fact that python do not force you to declare the type of a variable does not mean that you can apply the method of one type to another on your own imagination. And `append` is restricted to lists, applying it to a number you will also get an error.