# How can I get make a list like this? change the list [1,2] to [4,5] in Python

Tags: python, list

How can I make a list like this?

Assume `a = [1, 2]` and I want to print the result `[4,5]`

I tried:

```
a = [1, 2]+[3, 3]
print(a)
```

but the result shows: `[1, 2, 3, 3]`

I know that `[1, 2] + 3` is an error because list+integer is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension is one of the best options for doing something to every element in the list.

```
a_list = [1,2]
b_list = [x+3 for x in a_list]
[4, 5] # b_list output
```

You can also use `for loops` but they tend to be slower than list comprehension with larger data:

```
%%time
import numpy as np
a_list = np.arange(0,1000000,1)

b_list = []
for x in a_list:
    b_list.append(x+3)
```

`CPU times: total: 312 ms`
`Wall time: 319 ms`

```
%%time

a_list = np.arange(0,1000000,1)
b_list = [x+3 for x in a_list]
```

`CPU times: total: 234 ms`
`Wall time: 232 ms`

Answer (score 1):

So Here Is My Code, its just a `for` loop not List comprehension but it could also work!

Code:

```
a = [1, 2]
result = []
for i in a:
    result += [i + 3]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[4, 5]
```

**Explanation:**

We Declared A Variable `a` which contained a List `[1, 2]`. We then Declared a `result` variable! then we wrote a for loop means, **for** items **in** List `a` Which Would do something with every element in the list `a`. the 'something' here was adding the `itmes` for list a, added to 3, to list `result` as a List! Which would Add The existing element with three and store it to the other list! Then we print the `result` list

Hope This Helps! Micheal's Code is Faster But This Code is Good For Understanding Concepts!

Comment: `append()` is faster than `+=`, reference: [In Python, what is the difference between ".append" and "+="?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725782/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-append-and) ... In this case it probably doesn't matter but as data gets larger you can notice a difference

Comment: Thank You Michael! I appreciate your point and shall Note It! Thanks For The Help!

Answer (score 1):

```
# pip install numpy
import numpy as np

vector = np.array([1,2])
print(vector)
new_vector = vector + 3
print(new_vector)
```

BTW numpy makes python so popular nowadays - it is the core library for machine learning.

Answer (score -1):

First of all talking about your code

```
a = [1, 2]+[3, 3]
print(a)
```

in above piece of code you are trying to concatenate two list using "+" operator and that's why you get another list of number.

```
[1, 2, 3, 3] # i.e list
```

solution code:

```
a = [1,2]
b = [x+3 for x in a_list]
print(b)
```